# ¿Cómo añadir un icono a mi proyecto en codeblocks?

Tags: codeblocks

Eh estado haciendo varios proyectos en codeblocks, y puedo por ejemplo establecer el ícono de mi aplicacion a una ventana. Pero, ¿cómo le hago para que al compilar el proyecto me salga el ejecutable con el ícono que quiero que tenga?

Answer (score 0):

Añade un fichero resource.rc al proyecto con el siguiente contenido:

GLUT_ICON ICON "icono.ico"

o

IDR_APP_ICON ICON "icono.ico"

Depende un poco del proyecto, pero básicamente, se trata de indicarlo en el fichero resource.rc

Comment: ¿Se puede crear el fichero en las propiedades del proyecto o algo así? o lo creo y lo guardo en la carpeta raíz del proyecto?

Comment: Créalo nuevo si no tienes ya alguno. Pero mejor busca en google ahora que sabes qué hay que buscar, porque yo no sé de codeblocks ni nada, solo busqué tu pregunta en google.